# How can I trace xml document using xml schema using c#?

Tags: xml, user-interface, editor, schema

First, I am sorry for my English.
I can't speak English well.

I am making xml GUI editor using wpf.

(Similar http://www.felixgolubov.com/XMLEditor/Demo.html)

(My GUI : https://picasaweb.google.com/111372677877243737937/XmlEditor#5804892323036956914)

I finished to make GUI from xsd file.
Now I have to parse xml document and fill GUI forms.

What is the best method for this job?
Xml document have only elements and attributes.
But xml schema have many types like XmlSchemaComplexType, XmlSchemaChoice, XmlSchemaSequence, etc.
And multiple instances (MaxOccurs="unbounded")

I really need help for this job.
Thank you

Rainsong

Comment: If you need to validate your Xml document against the XSD you can use XmlReaer - here is an example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3740e0b5(v=vs.110).aspx